# JQuery .ajax GET working for everything except IE

Tags: jquery

```
  var json_uri = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + KEY + "/" + SECURE + "/values?alt=json";
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: json_uri,
     //cache: false, //tried this, didn't help
     dataType: "json", 
     success: function(data){
        alert("here");
        callback(data);
     }
  });
```

The alert is never called. When I add an error function, that function runs. This code works in EVERYTHING except IE. whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `callback=?` in the url for it to work in all browsers:

```
var KEY = 'o13394135408524254648.240766968415752635', SECURE = 'public';

var json_uri = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + KEY + "/" + SECURE + "/values?alt=json&callback=?";
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: json_uri,
     //cache: false, //tried this, didn't help
     dataType: "json", 
     success: function(data){
        alert("here");
        callback(data);
     }
  });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/gxLxA/1/